# How to load "content" from an external file when using register_block_pattern

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have no idea if this is even possible, but I am trying it anyway.
I have created a plugin where I want to load all my pre-designed patterns from in wordpress.

My plugin contains the following code (used to register my patterns)

```
function register_my_pattern() {
    register_block_pattern(
    'my-plugin/my-pattern',
        array(
            'title'       => __( 'My Pattern Name', 'my-plugin' ),
            'categories'    => array('my-pattern-category'),
            'content'     => '<!-- wp:group {"backgroundColor":"vivid-green-cyan","layout":{"type":"constrained"}} --> <div class="wp-block-group has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color has-background"><!-- wp:heading --> <h2 class="wp-block-heading">Testing my block</h2> <!-- /wp:heading --></div> <!-- /wp:group -->',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_pattern' );
```

The problem is that the content gets quite long for some patterns and I want an easy way edit them . I hate the fact that I need to minify my code to load it through register_block_pattern.
I would really like to put the actual content of the patterns in a seperate file and load it from there instead (so I don't have to minify them, and so that I can easily edit them).

So I tried doing this:
but this just prints the URL of the file when adding the pattern in the editor

```
function register_my_pattern() {
    register_block_pattern(
    'my-plugin/my-pattern',
        array(
            'title'       => __( 'My Pattern Name', 'my-plugin' ),
            'categories'    => array('my-pattern-category'),
            'content'     => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'my-pattern-file.php',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_pattern' );
```

I also tried this:
But this loads the content when opening the editor (even if the block isn't added)

```
function register_my_pattern() {
    register_block_pattern(
    'my-plugin/my-pattern',
        array(
            'title'       => __( 'My Pattern Name', 'my-plugin' ),
            'categories'    => array('my-pattern-category'),
            'content'     => include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'my-pattern-file.php'),
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_pattern' );
```

Is there any way to do this? Or is this completely impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You can register block patterns defined in PHP files by including them in the [patterns directory](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/block-patterns/#using-the-patterns-directory-to-register-patterns) in a block theme (NB. WordPress version 6.0+).

Although this is not a plugin-based solution like your example, it keeps the block pattern as PHP and part of the theme. The `*.php` pattern files are placed in `your-theme-name/patterns/` and automatically loaded into the Editor when the theme is active.

Answer (score 0):

Include the pattern and capture in the output buffer, then use that string in the register block pattern function.  it's not great and could probably get slow.  I hope in the future they make a function that can handle this and read the pattern header.

```
function register_my_pattern() {
      ob_start();
      include(plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'my-pattern-file.php');
      $pattern_string = ob_get_clean();

      register_block_pattern(
            'my-plugin/my-pattern',
            array(
                  'title'       => __('My Pattern Name', 'my-plugin'),
                  'categories'  => array('my-pattern-category'),
                  'content'     => $pattern_string,
            )
      );
}
add_action('init', 'register_my_pattern');
```